# How to group results by multiple fields?

Tags: views

I have values in database like:

`x submits file 1`

`x submits file 2`

`y submits file 1`

`y submits file 3`

`x submits file 1`(again)

I had my output with aggregation settings as group results together as

`x submits file 1`

`x submits file 2`

`y submits file 1`

`y submits file 3`

it just grouped file 1 submissions of x

i want it to be :

`x submits file 1,2`

`y submits file 1,3`

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D7 - you can achieve your grouping structure in Views with the help of the [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module.

You'd use the option "Use values of this field as a filter" for the field that produces x & y. And for the file name field you'd use the option "Merge unique values of this field".

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this by using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view

I created a view with a contextual filter to show the extra information in one field